# gitlab container registry login for error"x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" while Auto Devops

Tags: registry, gitlab-ci-runner

According to https://gist.github.com/solidnerd/1bf47f85457e4f90eea541586f7290da, I set a gitlab container registry on my gitlab(running on docker).I can login it with my gitlab user/password on every physical machine and all work normally.

But when I set auto-devops according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/, the build log gives this error: `"Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry.com:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"`.

I notise that this command `docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"` in the hidden file .gitlab-ci.yml on https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/blob/master/Auto-DevOps.gitlab-ci.yml. So I add this file to my project's root direction and replace those variables  $CI_REGISTRY_USER ,$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD, $CI_REGISTRY . But the same error.

Finally, I set the gitlab runner privileged valuse 'false' and succeed to login my container registry. But the privileged must be set as a valuse 'true' by the official document https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/. And another error occurred

`WARNING: Service runner-952743ac-project-2-concurrent-0-docker-0 probably didn't start properly.
service runner-952743ac-project-2-concurrent-0-docker-0-wait-for-service did timeout
2018-04-19T02:38:43.919411163Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)
2018-04-19T02:38:43.919496576Z Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
2018-04-19T02:38:43.919511733Z AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
2018-04-19T02:38:43.922167862Z mount: permission denied (are you root?)`

Any suggestions?